# Using DIV as link triggers redirect on new tab shortcut

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a section of a page (widget) which I would like to use as a link (clicking anywhere will go to a different page):

```
<!-- just an example. real application is quite a bit more complex -->
<div data-href="/page">
   <h1><a href="/page">Title of sample content</a></h1>
   <p>
        some content here with an image
        <img src="image.jpg">
   </p>
   <div>
        and many more elements in here
        <div>
             with nested structure with semantic meaning
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Since the section is `<div>`, I cant wrap it around `<a>` since that is against HTML spec. I also cant change the `divs` to `span` since they actually have semantic meaning.

Currently I attach a JS `click` event on which I change the browser location which effectively works as a link:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    window.location=$(this).data("href");
});
```

This works ok except when you `Ctrl+Click` or `Cmd+Click` on the `<a>` to open the link in the new tab. Since for this you are not explicitly doing right click, the browser registers it as a click hence the function gets executed anyway.

I guess I could check if any modifier key is pressed at the click event however I feel that is a bit cumbersome. Is there a nice JS solution for this?

Comment: Why complicate things? Just use an anchor instead of that div.

Comment: `<a>` cant have other `<div>` inside or at least if you stick to HTML spec - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: I know, change that one to span... It would even make more sense semantically since it has nothing but text (differently styled, I assume).

Comment: that is just a baby sample. the real html snippet has lots of divs there...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (jQuery for the click handler):

```
$(selector).click(function(e) {
  if(e.shiftKey) {
    //Shift-Click
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    //Ctrl+Click
  }
  if(e.altKey) {
    //Alt+Click
  }
});
```

You can handle whichever you want inside an if inside the click handler like shown above

Comment: thx of your suggestion however as per my question, I would prefer not to rely on checking for modifier keys